# How to fix 'Error: FIRESTORE (4.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown relation: array-contains'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I get this error message in my browser when I call my web page Error: FIRESTORE (4.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown relation: array-contains 
This is working on my local machine and started when i change a firestore query to use array-contains

I read about update my Admin SDK to 6.0.0 or later but i think is not working or I'm doing it wrong, I followed this steps from firebase page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-admin#admin_java_sdk_600
I have checked my Node.js version and is : v12.4.0

This is an exapmle of code that I implemented

```
 let doc = this.database.collection('Articles')
 .where('SerachIndex','array-contains',this.TextParams);
```

I'm specting make querys using arrar-contains operator but i don't know how to update admin SDK 4.8 to 6.0 or later in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you need to update to admin SDK 6.0 or later (now on version 8.6.1).

In your package.json for your nodeJS application change

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^4.8.0",
}
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
}
```

(or `"^8.6.1"` as that is the latest version)

Then run `npm install`

You may then need to consult the change logs (such as the link that you posted) to update your current implementation of the adminSDK if anything has been deprecated in that time.